# Getting updated data from angular provider to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a provider. It gets data from the config of an app, and updates an array `links`. Now I want to access the links array form the controller. But when controller calls the provider's $get function, it calls only the first time. When data in provider updates, the data is not updated in the controller.

Here is the provider

```
    this.$get = function () {
        return self.links;
    };
    this.addLink = function (link) {
        self.links.push(link);
    }
```

The addLink function is called in config of the app. And Here is how I am accessing the provider data in the controller :

```
var links = myProvider;
```

How to get updated data from the provider ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, `$get` in `provider` are supposed to be a factory, in your code it is a value not a factory function so it always the same value. Try wrapping it in another function.

```
this.$get = function() {
    return function() { return self.links;}
}
```

Comment: then how will i call it in controller ?  `var links = myProvider` ?

Comment: `var links = myProvider()`

Comment: Didn't fixed it. its getting the data but not updating it.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/324htoab/8/) My initial suggestion seems unnecessary, check the fiddle, it seems to be updating.